# using middleman framework, can;t make this code work on my project. (generating navigation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation, hyperlink, haml, middleman

### Hi guys, I can't seem to make this code work on my project.

**This is the code in my config.rb**

`active_nav = {:class => "Active"}` // Changed it to nav_active hoping it would work but it didn't.

```
  helpers do
    def nav_active(page)
      @page_id == page ? {:class => "Active"} : {}
    end
    def path(page)
      ("#{page}.html")
    end
  end
```

**This is the code in my _header.haml**

```
  %li{nav_active("index")}= link_to ('Home'), path('index')
  %li{nav_active("page")}= link_to ('Fast Facts'), path('page')
```

**My html links are:**

1. index.html.haml
2. page.html.haml

Output is still

```
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/page.html">Fast Facts</a></li>
```

Comment: What sets `@page_id`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Home path is set to `root_url` in your routes which is the `index` of `Homes Controller`. So you are getting the output link as "/" for Home.

Also note that you have correctly created the method `index` in a Home Controller and also created the file `index.html` in your view.

Also run `rake routes` to determine the paths you are getting for `Home Controller index` and ensure that it's fine.

UPDATE:

The index file paths are treated differently in rails because they are associated with a controller name. So like if your controller name is `Homes`, your index path is `homes_path`.
Probably, this seems to be a cause of different route formation. So change the path to it's
formation.

Alternatively, you can use

```
match '/homes/:index', :to => 'homes#index', :as => :index
```

The path formation by the above `:as` attribute will then be `index_path` or `index_url`.

Comment: hi sorry, but i'm still kinda new to rails so i really don't know where to put this code.

`match '/homes/:index', :to => 'homes#index', :as => :index`

Comment: this should be in routes.rb

Comment: hi, my project is a fork from middleman and i'm using [Amicus](https://github.com/nathos/amicus) template.

There is no routes.rb file generated from it. Still confused sorry

Comment: routes.rb is always necessary. It's in config folder.

Comment: Ved, you appear to be giving advice about Ruby on Rails, while Shiro is asking about Middleman.